SSO for Glassfish7 Software Portal
**web.xml ( Login.war ) **
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...

    <display-name>Login</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>jdbcRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login-error.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <name>JSESSIONID</name>
            <path>/</path>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <secure>false</secure> verwenden -->
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.primefaces.extensions.DELIVER_UNCOMPRESSED_RESOURCES</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>nova-light</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>


**web.xml (Start.war) **
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...

    <display-name>Startleiste</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>jdbcRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login/login-error.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> <!-- Timeout in Minuten -->
        <cookie-config>
            <name>JSESSIONID</name>
            <path>/</path>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <secure>false</secure> <!-- Ändern Sie dies zu true, wenn Sie HTTPS verwenden -->
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.primefaces.extensions.DELIVER_UNCOMPRESSED_RESOURCES</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>nova-light</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>


LoginController.java (Login.war)
package login.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import login.util.LoginService;
import login.util.entities.User;

@RequestScoped
@Named
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5346634778960677989L;

    private static final String URL = "myServerURL:8080";

   
    @Inject
    private LoginService loginService;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void login() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        User user = loginService.findUserByUsername(username);

        if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(SHA256Util.hashPassword(password))) {
            context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", user);
            try {
                System.out.println("Login successful, redirecting to start page.");
                context.getExternalContext().redirect(URL + "/Start");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Redirect failed: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid username or password.");
            context.addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Invalid username or password", null));
        }
    }

    public void logout() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("login.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Logout redirect failed: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


RedirektBean.java (Start.war)
package startleiste.glassfish;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext;
import jakarta.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginRedirectBean {

    public void redirectToLogin() {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        try {
            Principal userPrincipal = externalContext.getUserPrincipal();
            if (userPrincipal == null) {
                System.out.println("User ist nicht authentifiziert, Umleitung zur Login-Seite"); 
                externalContext.redirect("myServerURL/Login");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



Hello Everybody. I have a huge problem konfiguring SSO for my Glassfish7 application Server. I Want to develope a Software Portal with JSF, primefaces and Glassfish7 as a Application Server.
The plan was to konfigure a central Login-page - > after login User goes to the Navigationpage. If u access the navigation page without a login before, the application redirects you to login page.
I did that in to different WARs
Login.war
Start.war
If i successfully logged in - the Application redirects me instantly to Login.war
why is that ?

It Seems like the User isnt shared in the different Wars, right ? I configured a JDBC realm in Glassfish and activated SSO.
I don´t know what to do...
hopefully someone can help me.
Thanks in advance
I want to redirect user to Start.war from Login.war with only 1 login to application user (SSO)
if the user whants to access Start.war and he´s not logged in - the system should redirect him to Login.war

are you sure that your login application uses the realm to authenticate the user? I only see context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", user); in the login method. Your code doesn't use the jdbcRealm at all, you go directly to database. GlassFish has no way to know whether a user is authenticated or not, and then cannot pass the information to another app for SSO. Unfortunately, it seems that most examples on the internet show something similar to your code, but that only works for a single application and only if you have a custom servlet filter that prevents access to secure pages if not authenticated. In other words, the whole security mechanism is completely custom and doesn't rely on the server, nor the server knows anything about it.
Here's an tutorial on how to do what you want so that your application authenticates using the JDBC realm: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxce.html
You should call the following in your login() method:
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

        try {
            request.login(username, password);
            // Redirect to the home page or a secured page
            return "welcome?faces-redirect=true";
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // Authentication failed

